# Option Strict causing compiling error within LINQ statement (implicit conversion 'Object' to 'Control')

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

We're currently converting a VB project to C#, and starting by enabling Option Strict.  When enabled, the following line generates an error:

```
Dim visiblePanelCount As Integer = (From c As Control In pnl_AdminPageLinks.Controls 
                                     Where TypeOf (c) Is Panel AndAlso c.Visible 
                                     Select c).Count()
```

The red underline is on `As Control` with the error:

> BC30512   Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object'
> to 'Control'

I understand what the error means, but cannot understand where the type of `Object` is being created (as I believe that `.Controls` is a collection of type `Control`).

A second example which makes even less sense to me is *"Object to DataRow"* same error under `As DataRow` in this line:

```
Return (From dr As DataRow In MyDataTable.Rows ' error on As DataRow
        Select New MyClass() With {
            .Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item("Id")),
            .UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item("UserId"))
        }).ToList()
```

I convert the code to C# which generated the same logic, so don't understand VB.Net's underlying problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that LINQ is based on the generic `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface and that `Controls` collection, despite containing only controls, does not implement `IEnumerable(Of Control)`. It only implements `IEnumerable` so, when it is enumerated, it provides an `Object` reference only. The way to go from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable(Of T)` is with the `Cast(Of T)` method:

```vb
Dim visiblePanelCount = (From c In pnl_AdminPageLinks.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
                         Where TypeOf (c) Is Panel AndAlso c.Visible 
                         Select c).Count()
```

You can do away with the type check by calling `OfType(Of T)` too, which also moots the `Cast(Of T)` call:

```vb
Dim visiblePanelCount = (From c In pnl_AdminPageLinks.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
                         Where c.Visible 
                         Select c).Count()
```

You can also omit the `Select` clause in VB if you are simply selecting the original query item:

```vb
Dim visiblePanelCount = (From c In pnl_AdminPageLinks.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
                         Where c.Visible).Count()
```

Given that the `Count` method will filter as well, you can simplify that query even further:

```vb
Dim visiblePanelCount = pnl_AdminPageLinks.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)().Count(Function(p) p.Visible)
```

Comment: Fantastic answer; thank you.  Are the parentheses required at the end of `.OfType(Of Panel)()`?  With the goal of a c# conversion, c# and VB compile without, but intellisense includes them, so wondered what best practice is?

Comment: @EvilDr, they're not required in VB but I always include the empty parentheses on method calls. I think that it's especially good to do so on generic methods because, otherwise, the generic type parameter can be mistaken for a regular method parameter. In C#, the parentheses are required on all method calls so, if you're interested in maximum compatibility, use them in VB too.